# Is 'so much as' an adverbial modifier in this example?

Tags: determiners, adverbials, adjuncts, correlative-conjunctions

> He took my money without **so much as** a thank you.

In this sentence, is 'so much as' an adverbial modifier (adjunct) of the indefinite article (determiner) 'a'? Or can we interpret it as a correlative conjunction, the two conjoined objects being 'much' and 'thank you'?

Another similar phrase is 'not so much ... as.' I would definitely call this a correlative conjunction. See this example (from Google definitions):

> The novel was **not so much** finished **as** unfinishable.'

Comment: *So much as* must modify "a thank you," not just the article. Did he thank you? Less than a thank you; not even a thank you; certainly a thank you.

Comment: Watch out for typos when asking about mistakes. It's **AN** adverbial marker (not _and_), and it's _not **so** much ... as_ (rather than *_such much_). And it can be an adverbial modifier if you want to call it one; grammatical terminology is not fixed by law. I'd call _without so much as a `politeness_marker`_ a fixed phrase, personally. The one with _so much ... as_ is a negative polarity item and requires the _not_ before _so_.

Comment: @MJ Ada JL is right. You really should avoid making silly mistakes like the one in the title and the ungrammatical *"such much as".

Comment: Apologies for the mistakes. I wrote this quite quickly, and I had a bit of writer's blindness. Even after you mentioned 'such much', I struggled to spot it.

Answer (score 1):

'So much as' is a scalar particle with the same meaning as that of 'even' used as a scalar particle. It is a negative polarity item, not appearing in positive declarative clauses:

- *John didn't attend even one lecture last term.*
- *John didn't attend so much as one lecture last term.*

[[On the typology of scalar particles; Luka Crniˇc](http://lukacrnic.com/pdfs/talk-bgu.pdf)]

The function of these is to emphasise the whole statement.

- *John didn't attend one lecture last term. **Not one!***

.................

- *He was not tired so much as exhausted.*

on the other hand uses 'not X so much as Y' as a reformulatory device, showing that a different descriptor is more appropriate /correct.

- *Not tired ... **exhausted!***